# relocation R_X86_64_32 against symbol `ff_a64_muxer' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, openscenegraph

I am trying to build osg v 3.4 following the [github readme](https://github.com/openscenegraph/OpenSceneGraph/tree/OpenSceneGraph-3.4), however i get the following compilation error after on the `make VERBOSE=1` step:

```
[ 94%] Linking CXX shared module ../../../lib/osgPlugins-3.4.0/osgdb_ffmpeg.so
cd /home/workdir/osg_tst/osg/build/src/osgPlugins/ffmpeg && /usr/local/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/osgdb_ffmpeg.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/local/bin/c++ -fPIC  -Wall -Wparentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-import -pedantic -Wreturn-type -Wmissing-braces -Wunknown-pragmas -Wunused -Wno-deprecated-declarations -O3 -DNDEBUG -shared  -o ../../../lib/osgPlugins-3.4.0/osgdb_ffmpeg.so CMakeFiles/osgdb_ffmpeg.dir/FFmpegClocks.o CMakeFiles/osgdb_ffmpeg.dir/FFmpegDecoderAudio.o CMakeFiles/osgdb_ffmpeg.dir/FFmpegDecoder.o CMakeFiles/osgdb_ffmpeg.dir/FFmpegDecoderVideo.o CMakeFiles/osgdb_ffmpeg.dir/FFmpegImageStream.o CMakeFiles/osgdb_ffmpeg.dir/FFmpegAudioStream.o CMakeFiles/osgdb_ffmpeg.dir/FFmpegParameters.o CMakeFiles/osgdb_ffmpeg.dir/ReaderWriterFFmpeg.o  -Wl,-rpath,/home/workdir/osg_tst/osg/build/lib: ../../../lib/libosgDB.so.3.4.0 ../../../lib/libosgUtil.so.3.4.0 -Wl,-Bstatic -lavformat -lavdevice -lavcodec -lavutil -lswscale -lswresample -Wl,-Bdynamic ../../../lib/libosg.so.3.4.0 ../../../lib/libOpenThreads.so.3.3.0 -lpthread -lm -lrt -ldl -lz -lGL 
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12.2.0/../../../libavformat.a(allformats.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against symbol `ff_a64_muxer' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12.2.0/../../../libavformat.a(amr.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12.2.0/../../../libavformat.a(anm.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12.2.0/../../../libavformat.a(apc.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
.
.
.
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [src/osgPlugins/ffmpeg/CMakeFiles/osgdb_ffmpeg.dir/build.make:224: lib/osgPlugins-3.4.0/osgdb_ffmpeg.so] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/workdir/osg_tst/osg/build'
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:5205: src/osgPlugins/ffmpeg/CMakeFiles/osgdb_ffmpeg.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/workdir/osg_tst/osg/build'
make: *** [Makefile:136: all] Error 2
```

The list of error goes on, but i am only showing the first three for clarity, as they all match the same error.

The error recommends using the -fPIC option, however it is clearly already in use in the command displayed.

From the [gcc documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html#Code-Gen-Options) It should have something to do with the architecture used, but the project is also already in 64 bit, as is my linux architecture in x86_64, so what am i missing here?

Comment: Why `-Wl,-Bstatic`? If it's something cmake generates by default, then it's a bug in the build script. Static libraries cannot be expected to be position-independent.

Answer (score 2):

The `-fPIC` problem isn't with the project you're compiling, but with the `ffmpeg` binaries which you are linking against. Note that the compiler error references `/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12.2.0/../../../libavformat.a`, which is your system installation of `libavformat`, part of the `ffmpeg` project.

I'd recommend building `ffmpeg` from source by following the instructions [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu). If you pass `--enable-pic` to the `configure` script, then it will be compiled with the `-fPIC` flag, enabling you to link against it without error.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, it was indeed coming from my ffmpeg installation, i also add to use these flags on configure command before rebuildint it:
 --enable-pic --enable-shared